# Firefox is acting weird on this form

Tags: html, firefox, forms

I am trying to float a `<button>` to the right. the `<button>` is outside of `<form>` but is on the same line. For some reason this is not working in FF. I made my form background red and found out that the `<button>` is still in the `<form>` in FF even though its not! Every other browser works fine, the `<button>` is not in the `<form>`.

Screenshot:(left is chrome...the one with http:// and the right is Firefox

[alt text http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/3824/ffchrome.png](http://img375.imageshack.us/img375/3824/ffchrome.png)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="url" placeholder="http://" />
  <input type="submit" value="Crypt" />
</form>
  <button type="button"> ? </button>
```

CSS: (Took out the unnecessary code)

```
section.crypter {
  padding: 25px;  
  }
section.crypter form {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
/* Input */
section.crypter input[type="url"] {
  border:1px solid #666;
  color: #939393;
  font: italic bold 1.7em Verdana, Arial, Serif;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  width: 240px;
  }
section.crypter input[type="submit"] {
  border:1px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  font: 2em Verdana, Arial, Serif;
  margin:0 0 0 -10px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  }

section.crypter input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;/* Firefox hack */
  }
section.crypter button {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without your css.

Comment: Being new to coding for only a couple months, I didn't know Firefox had these kinda problems. :/ Thought IE was the bad guy.

Comment: Show us CSS + what version of Firefox? Have you tested multiple versions? Don't be so quick to blame Firefox you're probably not doing this the "best practice" way.

Comment: @Kawohi, there's enough ambiguity in the CSS specs that it's possible for browsers to display different content without one being the "bad guy". IE has a reputation of violating the specs, but just because something looks good in, say, WebKit doesn't guarantee it will look good in Firefox.

Comment: Firefox  3.6.8 and I also added the CSS

Comment: and also no images in the form, its all css. So I don't think images is a problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys, I figured it out thanks to Kroc Camen. In Firefox, I cannot float something to the right unless it is first in order within the wrapping element. (A engine quirk since the 90's) haha Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with firefox 3.6.8 and did not have the issues you got. I also don't think Firefox will manipulate the DOM (moving the button into the form tag), what seams to happen.

So I guess its one of your Firefox extensions, that causes the issue.

Comment: I uninstall and reinstall FF and the same thing still happens :(

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying to uninstall and install firefox and the good old fashion reboot.